# Need help with regression model and interpretation of results

Tags: multiple-regression

I am learning regression and am new to statistics. I am using R for regression. My data has 3 dependent variables and 4 independent variables including 1 categorical variable. I am not sure which model is suitable for regression. I used `glm` and got this result:

```
Call:  glm(formula = sci ~ inv + term + partic + ordered(colab_type), 
    data = colab)

Coefficients:
          (Intercept)                    inv                   term  
             -0.04956                0.02298                0.03247  
               partic  ordered(colab_type).L  
              0.02750                0.91567  

Degrees of Freedom: 30722 Total (i.e. Null);  30718 Residual
Null Deviance:      203100 
Residual Deviance: 181000   AIC: 141700
> summary(model1)

Call:
glm(formula = sci ~ inv + term + partic + ordered(colab_type), 
    data = colab)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-12.101   -0.765   -0.245    0.225  100.402  

Coefficients:
                        Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)           -0.0495614  0.0431617  -1.148    0.251    
inv                    0.0229839  0.0017333  13.261   <2e-16 ***
term                   0.0324703  0.0008066  40.256   <2e-16 ***
partic                 0.0275027  0.0023607  11.650   <2e-16 ***
ordered(colab_type).L  0.9156728  0.0485840  18.847   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for gaussian family taken to be 5.893817)

    Null deviance: 203101  on 30722  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 181046  on 30718  degrees of freedom
AIC: 141695

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 2


Call:  glm(formula = comer ~ inv + term + partic + ordered(colab_type), 
    data = colab)

Coefficients:
          (Intercept)                    inv                   term  
            0.2948466              0.0003122              0.0010570  
               partic  ordered(colab_type).L  
            0.0086836             -0.4263058  

Degrees of Freedom: 30722 Total (i.e. Null);  30718 Residual
Null Deviance:      1111000 
Residual Deviance: 1110000  AIC: 197400
> summary(model3)

Call:
glm(formula = comer ~ inv + term + partic + ordered(colab_type), 
    data = colab)

Deviance Residuals: 
   Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max  
 -4.03   -0.70   -0.66   -0.63  391.28  

Coefficients:
                        Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)            0.2948466  0.1068933   2.758 0.005813 ** 
inv                    0.0003122  0.0042925   0.073 0.942017    
term                   0.0010570  0.0019976   0.529 0.596709    
partic                 0.0086836  0.0058463   1.485 0.137471    
ordered(colab_type).L -0.4263058  0.1203220  -3.543 0.000396 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for gaussian family taken to be 36.14933)

    Null deviance: 1111023  on 30722  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 1110435  on 30718  degrees of freedom
AIC: 197419

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 2
```

I get similar results for other variables as well. Can anyone determine if this model is correct? How are these results interpreted?